# How to properly get when the redux dispatch is done, to then render a Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I use react 18.2.0, redux 4.2.0 and redux thunk

I want to wait until my dispatch is done, so I can take the data it got from the server and render a component with that data

I try to do the following in my component:

```
import store from '../redux/store'; 

const featureInfoA = useSelector(featureInfo) 
const featureErrorA = useSelector(featureError) 
const featureStatusA = useSelector(featureStatus) 
    
const clickFeatureFromList = (id) =>  { 
  //start dispatching
  dispatch(fetchFeatureInfoById({ id, category })) 
    .then((e) => {
      console.log('BINGO THEN ', featureInfoA, featureErrorA, featureStatusA);
    })
}

//check store when a specific state changed and then get its data and render a component
store.subscribe(() => {
  const state = store.getState()
  if (state.features.status == 'succeeded' || state.features.status == 'failed') {
    console.log('BINGO SUBSCRIBE ', featureInfoA);
    accordionDetailsRootGlobal.render(<ContextInfo featureData={featureInfoA} />);
  } 
})
```

The issue is that in my console I see:

- `BINGO SUBSCRIBE a` multiple times
- and then the `DATA from store` that is inside the store
- and then the `BINGO THEN  a null idle` that  is in the `then` after calling dispatch

I think that the log of the store should be first

Why I see "BINGO SUBSCRIBE a" that is inside the `store.subscribe` multiple times?

Why I never see the final data that came from the server? "BINGO THEN  a null idle" contains the initial state, even though "DATA from store" brought back data.

By the way, this my store, for features

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const FEATURE_URL = 'http://localhost:3500/map'

//status : idle, loading, succeeded, failed
const initialState = {
    info:'a',
    status:'idle',
    error:null
}

export const fetchFeatureInfoById = createAsyncThunk('feature/fetchInfoById', (originalData) => {
    console.log('fetchFeatureInfoById originalData ', originalData);
    fetch(FEATURE_URL + '/feature/' + originalData.id + '/' + originalData.category)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log('DATA from store ', data);
        return data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        return error.message;
    });
})

export const featuresSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'features',
    initialState,
    reducers: { 
        featureInfoById: {
            reducer(state, action) {
                //do something with the id 
                console.log('feature state ', ' -- state : ',state.status, ' -- action : ', action);
            },
            prepare(category, id) {
                return{
                    payload:{
                        category,
                        id
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    extraReducers(builder) {
        builder
        .addCase(fetchFeatureInfoById.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'loading'
        })
        .addCase(fetchFeatureInfoById.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'failed'
            state.error = action.error.message
        })
        .addCase(fetchFeatureInfoById.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            console.log('fulfilled data store ', state, action);
            state.status = 'succeeded'
            state.info = action.palyload
        })
    }
  }) 
   
  export const featureInfo = (state) => state.features.info;
  export const featureError = (state) => state.features.error;
  export const featureStatus = (state) => state.features.status;
  export const {featureInfoById} = featuresSlice.actions
  export default featuresSlice.reducer
```

I just want to get the data after the dispatch is done, to render a component with them. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong and how can I fix that.

Comment: "Why I see 'BINGO SUBSCRIBE' a that is inside the `store.subscribe` multiple times"? - It's probably because you are subscribing to the store as an unexpected side-effect. Can you edit the post to include a more complete and cohesive [mcve] so it's clear what exactly is in a React component and when it's called?

Comment: I managed to make it half-work, but I still somehow have issues with updating the store the first time. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058386/useselector-updates-only-the-second-time-using-redux-toolkit) Thanks

Comment: Can you [edit] at least the first snippet to be a more complete [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

1. 

> Why I see "BINGO SUBSCRIBE a" that is inside the store.subscribe
> multiple times?

[The docs mention](https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener):

> Adds a change listener. It will be called any time an action is
> dispatched, and some part of the state tree may potentially have
> changed.

So basically each time any action is dispatched and any part of the state tree might have been changed it will be triggered. This refers to your entire store (not just `featuresSlice`).

Another potential reason is that you are subscribing each time the component is mounted, but never unsubscribing (so you might have multiple subscriptions at the same time). If you really want to keep this, a fix would be to subscribe inside an useEffect unsubscribe on unmount (something like):

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribeFn = store.subscribe(() => {...})
  return unsubscribeFn
}
```

---

2. 

> Why I never see the final data that came from the server? "BINGO THEN
> a null idle" contains the initial state, even though "DATA from store"
> brought back data.

This is most likely because your `fetchFeatureInfoById` is not returning anything (please note that the `return data;` part is inside a callback, but the main function doesn't return anything) so in your extra reducer `action.payload` has no value.

So what you want to do in order to be able to properly set the slice state from the slice extra reducer is returning the fetch result from the `fetchFeatureInfoById` function. So basically your function would look something like:

```
export const fetchFeatureInfoById = createAsyncThunk('feature/fetchInfoById', (originalData) => {
    console.log('fetchFeatureInfoById originalData ', originalData);
    // Add the return keyword before the fetch from the next line
    return fetch(FEATURE_URL + '/feature/' + originalData.id + '/' + originalData.category)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log('DATA from store ', data);
        return data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        return error.message;
    });
})
```

---

PS: Without a reproducible example is not 100% this will fix all your problems, but it should at the very least point you in the right direction.

---

Extra suggestions:

1. (related to first answer): I think you can at least use an useEffect? It would be way more efficient to only trigger the an effect when `accordionDetailsRootGlobal` changes or `featureInfoA` (so basically have an useEffect with this 2 dependencies and render the `ContextInfo` when one of this 2 change, rather than rendering on every store update). Something like:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (featureInfoA)
      accordionDetailsRootGlobal.render(<ContextInfo featureData={featureInfoA} />)
  }, [accordionDetailsRootGlobal, featureInfoA])
```

2. inside `fetchFeatureInfoById` on the catch you don't throw any error. This will prevent `.addCase(fetchFeatureInfoById.rejected ...` from being called (since, even if your fetch fails, the function won't throw any error). So you should probably remove the catch part, or throw an error inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the `store.subscribe` thing.

The selector is supposed to update and it will cause a render of your component. So, initially featureInfoA is undefined but after the promise is resolved it will update the store which will trigger a render in your component

```
import store from '../redux/store'; 

const featureInfoA = useSelector(featureInfo) 
const featureErrorA = useSelector(featureError) 
const featureStatusA = useSelector(featureStatus) 
    
const clickFeatureFromList =(id) =>  { 
  //start dispatching
  dispatch(fetchFeatureInfoById({id, category})) 
}

// add some logic here to check if featureInfoA has value
if(featureErrorA) return <div>Error</div>

if(featureStatusA === "loading") return <div>Loading...</div>

if(featureInfoA) return <div>{featureInfoA}</div>
```

Comment: I understand, but I cannot just do `if(featureInfoA) return <div>{featureInfoA}</div>` because I dynamically append a component with the data of the dispatch to a `div` that is not always the same. In my code I have `accordionDetailsRootGlobal.render(<ContextInfo featureData={featureInfoA} />);` , and `accordionDetailsRootGlobal` is a `getElementById` that changes each time. Simply doing `return <div>{featureInfoA}</div>` unfortunately is not an option. Thanks

Comment: I managed to make it half-work, but I still somehow have issues with updating the store the first time. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058386/useselector-updates-only-the-second-time-using-redux-toolkit) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Think this might be a better approach to deal with dispatch when you want to observe your data after you request successfully handled

```
   const clickFeatureFromList =async (id) =>  { 
    
      //start dispatching
     const result = await dispatch(fetchFeatureInfoById({ id, category }))
     if (fetchFeatureInfoById.fulfilled.match(result)) { 
     const {payload} = result
     console.log('BINGO THEN ', featureInfoA, featureErrorA, featureStatusA);

   }
    }
```