# useSelector updates only the second time, using Redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have the following slice in my store.

```
//status : idle, loading, succeeded, failed
const initialState = {
    info:'a',
    status:'idle',
    error:null
}

//to get data from server 
export const fetchFeatureInfoById = createAsyncThunk('feature/fetchInfoById', async (originalData) => {
    console.log('fetchFeatureInfoById originalData ', originalData);
    const response = await axios.get(FEATURE_URL+'/feature/'+originalData.id+'/'+originalData.category)
    console.log('DATA from server ', response);
    return response.data
})

//slice with reducers 
export const featuresSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'features',
    initialState,
    reducers: { 
        featureInfoById:{
            reducer(state, action){
                //do something with the id 
                console.log('feature state ', ' -- state : ',state.status, ' -- action : ', action);
            },
            prepare(category, id){
                return{
                    payload:{
                        category,
                        id
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    extraReducers(builder){
        builder
        .addCase(fetchFeatureInfoById.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'loading'
        })
        .addCase(fetchFeatureInfoById.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'failed';
            return state;
            // state.error = action.error.message;
            console.log('rejected data store ', state, action); 
        })
        .addCase(fetchFeatureInfoById.fulfilled, (state, action) => { 
            // state.status = 'succeeded';
            // state.info = action.payload;
            let a = {
                info:action.payload,
                status:'succeeded',
                error:null
            }
            return a;
            // console.log('fulfilled data store ', state, action);
            // return action.payload;
        })
    }
  }) 

//exporting just info of feature
export const featureInfo = (state) => state.features.info;
```

In my Component, I have

```
import store from '../redux/store'; 
import {useSelector,useDispatch} from "react-redux"; 
import { featureInfo, featureError, featureStatus, featureInfoById, fetchFeatureInfoById } from "../redux/features";
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';  

const featureInfoA = useSelector(featureInfo) 
const clickFeatureFromList =( sl, s, id, e, groupid, c) => (event, isExpanded) =>  { 
    store.subscribe(()=>{
      const state = store.getState()
      if (state.features.status=='succeeded' || state.features.status=='failed') {
        console.log('BINGO SUBSCRIBE ', featureInfoA); 
      } 
    })

    dispatch(fetchFeatureInfoById({id, category:'ex'}))
    .then((e)=>{
      console.log('BINGO THEN ', featureInfoA, featureErrorA, featureStatusA);
      accordionDetailsRootGlobal.render(<ContextInfo/>);
    }) 
  }
```

The first time I click a button to call the `clickFeatureFromList` the logs I get are

```
BINGO SUBSCRIBE  a
BINGO THEN  a null idle
```

this means that somehow the state never changes, I get the initial one

the second time I click a button to call the `clickFeatureFromList` the logs I get are normal, eg

```
BINGO SUBSCRIBE  a
BINGO SUBSCRIBE  {success: false, msg: 'resolved error'}
BINGO SUBSCRIBE  {success: false, msg: 'resolved error'}
BINGO THEN  {success: false, msg: 'resolved error'} null succeeded
```

this is correct, state changes.

Why state does not change the first time? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT
as you can see in  `.addCase(fetchFeatureInfoById.fulfilled, (state, action) => {` I tried different syntaxes, nothing works

**EDIT**

check this **[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-haslett-os7pf3?file=/src/index.js)** to see what is wrong. Open the console of the sandbox to see errors

Comment: Why are you still using `store.subscribe` manually/directly? This is what `useSelector` does for you. Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] so we can tell what is being called, when and from where?

Comment: I use `store.subscribe` just to see what is going on in store, its not to get the data from the api. I have a huge file, but I will try to create a reproducable example and post the link

Comment: Just use `store.getState()` then, no need to create subscriptions. Thanks for considering creating a running demo that we can check live.

Comment: check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-haslett-os7pf3?file=/src/index.js). Open the console of the sandbox to see errors. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've looked at the sandbox. Upon clicking the "test" button I see the state update on the first click. This is even confirmed in the redux dev tools.

[image]

I think there are at least a couple issues occurring here, both related to Javascript closures. The first is about a stale closure over the selected `featureInfoA`, `featureErrorA`, `featureStatusA` states in the callback (*`clickFeatureFromList` above and `testme` in the sandbox*), while the second is about accessing the ***current*** Redux state while still in the callback scope (*the same closure*).

Using the code from your sandbox this is what I'd suggest as an implementation so you can (a) access the Redux state correctly in the callback Promise chain and (b) log the states in a meaningful way.

Code:

```
export function Counter() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const featureInfoA = useSelector(featureInfo);
  const featureErrorA = useSelector(featureError);
  const featureStatusA = useSelector(featureStatus);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Render ", {
      features: {
        info: featureInfoA,
        error: featureErrorA,
        status: featureStatusA
      }
    });
  }, [featureErrorA, featureInfoA, featureStatusA])

  const testme = (id, category) => {
    dispatch(fetchFeatureInfoById({ id, category })).then((e) => {
      const state = store.getState();
      console.log("BINGO THEN closure", {
        features: {
          info: featureInfoA,
          error: featureErrorA,
          status: featureStatusA
        }
      });
      console.log("BINGO THEN state", state);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => testme(4, "todos")}>test</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

- The `useEffect` hook logs the selected state per render cycle
- The current store's state value is accessed ***in*** the `.then` callback, not outside the Promise chain
- The `.then` is also logging the selected state that was closed over in callback scope so you could see its staleness

Running the above code and clicking the "test" button exactly once produces the following log output. I'll annotate the logs to the code.

[image]

1. Initial render `Render  {"info":"a","status":"idle","error":null}`
2. "test" button clicked
3. Asynchronous action log `fetchFeatureInfoById originalData {id: 4, category: "todos"}`
4. Rerender because action pending `Render  {"info":"a","status":"loading","error":null}`
5. `DATA from server  {data: Object, status: 200, statusText: "", headers: AxiosHeaders, config: Object…}`
6. In the Promise chain

   - The stale enclosure `BINGO THEN closure {"info":"a","status":"idle","error":null}`
   - The current state `BINGO THEN state {"features":{"info":{"userId":1,"id":4,"title":"et porro tempora","completed":true},"status":"succeeded","error":null}}`
7. Rerender because action fulfilled, state updated `Render  {"info":{"userId":1,"id":4,"title":"et porro tempora","completed":true},"status":"succeeded","error":null}`

[image: Edit useselector-updates-only-the-second-time-using-redux-toolkit]